# Converter data e hora da Nota Fiscal Eletrônica - Javascript

Tags: javascript, nfe

A nota fiscal eletrônica gera um qr-code à partir de uma url. Essa url possui diversos parâmetros, um deles é a data e hora da emissão, que segundo a documentação da receita reza:

> O valor deverá corresponder à conversão para hexadecimal em caixa
>   baixa do valor no padrão UTC com máscara.

Em uma url que possuo, esse campo possui 50 bytes, conforme abaixo:

```
dhEmi=323031382D30372D32345431323A31323A33352D30333A3030
```

Eu gostaria de saber como posso converter este valor para um datetime válido em javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hex2date(hexx) {
       const hex = hexx.toString();
       let datestr = '';
       for (let i = 0; (i < hex.length && hex.substr(i, 2) !== '00'); i += 2)
           datestr += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
       return datestr;
   }
```